# Which control to build a Hex-Editor?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hex-editors

I want to create a Hex-Editor using XAML/WPF and C#, but I need somesort of Table-Control to display the File-Content. It should have a Textbox in each Column to view Address, view and edit Hex-Values and ASCII-Values.

Later I want to add additional Columns, like Unicode or something. 
The User should be able to view/hide Columns.

What Controls do I need to do that?

I thought of a `ListView`, with a `GridView` to define the Columns and a TextBox in each Column.
But `ListView` is more of a `Multi-Row` Control.
Can you give me a hint on which Control I sould use?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  [Be.HexEditor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hexbox/) has a hexbox reusable control.

Comment: Unfortuantelly Be.HexEditor is Windows Forms application, not WPF

Comment: i know that WindowsForms control can be hosted in WPF, I even managed to do that. Unfortunately there is known issues with Z-Position if WindowsHostedControl in WPF. Therefore It would be great to have a hint regarding which control could be used in WPF to build similar app

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I'd agree with that comment though, if the existing Be.HexEditor control meets your needs, that would be the best option.

Otherwise, I might recommend the [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) for that sort of tabular viewing and entry. If you search google there are lots of examples and tutorials (like [this one](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You can check my project. Wpf hexeditor. I think it can be help you :)

You can use it very easily in Wpf or WinForm application. Download the code and test the Wpf (C#, VB.NET) and WinForm (C#) samples.

https://github.com/abbaye/WPFHexEditorControl

```
<!-- XAML -->
<Control:HexaEditor/>
<Control:HexaEditor Width="NaN" Height="NaN"/>
<Control:HexaEditor Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
<Control:HexaEditor FileName={Binding FileNamePath} Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
```

[image: Image1]

Comment: You need to disclose that this is your project you're linking to. See [the help center](/help/promotion)

Comment: How I can disclose that please :)

Comment: Do we have same HexEditor for .net 4.6.1 version?

Comment: You can add NET45 ou NET461 in project file and build the project.  :)

Comment: Derek, this control looks excessive. Is it possible to customize it to see ONLY hex editor? Means just one line of hex digits + editing 'em.

Comment: Yes you can with build-in properties :) (Sorry for delay)